# Calling Dynamics Crm Online XrmServiceContext results in an exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I just registered for an online 365 trial version.

I copy-pasted the Walkthrough sample code appearing [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803(v=crm.7).aspx), and changed the Url, Username and Password values inside the App.config, so that they have the relevant values.

However, I get an exception when calling `xrm.SaveChanges()`:

Content of exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll

Content of Message:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

Content of Inner Exception:

> Code: {System.ServiceModel.FaultCode}, Message: Invalid Request

Stack trace:

> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions
>   options)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges()
>
> at CRMSimpleConsole1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\home\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CRMSimpleConsole1\CRMSimpleConsole1\Program.cs:line 32
>
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)
>
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() I also get an exception
>   when calling xrm.Create(): An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Note that the same happens for any call to the service (e.g., `xrm.Create()`.

I searched for this on the web, and people say it is caused because of wrong time sync. Well, at least in the CRM Settings area, the time zone is correct, so I don't what to do.

Comment: You registered for a trial of Dynamics 365 and you are checking an example for CRM 2015? Have you checked if the example for Dynamics 365 (CRM 2016) works?

Comment: I didnt find one for 2016

Comment: Still it does not justify using example for different version of CRM. In CRM 2016 you should use Xrm.Tooling for connection not Xrm.Client. You should describe what you should try to achieve to get better help, following a tutorial for wrong version of CRM (and making that a problem on StackOverflow) does not make sense

Answer (score 2):

The Xrm.Client is deprecated and as others have mentioned, the way to connect via a console app is CrmServiceClient, which is in the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector library.

Using NuGet you can get the [Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) package and you'll be off to the races.

Here are a couple other helpful links:

[Build Windows client applications using the XRM tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689057.aspx)

[Sample: Quick start for XRM Tooling API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689019.aspx)

And here's a connection string example for Dyn365 online:

```
<add name="dev26" connectionString="Url=https://dev26.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@dev26.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Pass; AuthType=Office365" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the connection string given in Microsoft's walkthrough, you must also

- remove `Domain=CONTOSO`
- add `AuthType=Office365`

Comment: Yeah, I also did both, with no results. I guess there are problems with the assemblies I'm using: The linked sample code is for 2015. However, I'm trying to use it for CRM2016 Online, with 2015's assemblies - since Microsoft.Xrm.Client doesn't exist in 2015. What else should I do?